# Integrating hoverIntent with "mousedown"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseover, hoverintent

Hey all, I've got an HTML table, and I'm trying to create some Excel style functions like copying and selecting cells and such. I had some cool effects going (using jQuery's mousedown on table cells), but it was too jumpy. I learned about hoverIntent, but I can't figure out how to implement it. How would it fit in with this (simplified copy function):

```
$("table#grid td").mousedown(function () {
    // this cell has the value to copy; retrieve and store it
    mouseDown = true;
}).mouseover(function () {
    if(mouseDown) {
        // copy value into this cell
    }
};

$(document).mouseup(function () {
    mouseDown = false;
    // reset copy info
}
```

The problem is that it would register a mouseover more than once (some times) when crossing td borders, which was making formatting selected/deselected cells a nightmare.

I hope this makes sense. I'm quite new to jQuery, but trying hard.

Comment: To anyone looking to do something similar, check this out... [jQuery US - Selectable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/selectable/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely tricky. HoverIntent will help with sloppy or accidental mousing, but it may not solve your problems. Anything I would write here for how to use it would just be a reproduction of the [hoverIntent documentation](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html).

In the event that this is not enough, I suggest you become better acquainted with [jQuery's event object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/). Once you do, you'll see that you have to do a good bit of micromanagement, using `event.target`, `event.currentTarget`, and/or `event.relatedTarget`.

In other words, compare your event targets with cell formatting – and possibly a log of selected cells – to determine whether a given mouseover trigger is a "misfire" or not.